# Default naming policy for columns - is it possible? (JPA)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, configuration

JPA newbie here. Here's my question:

Say we have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="thingies")
public class Thingy implements Serializable {
    private Long thingyId;
    private String thingyName;
    private Integer thingyPrice;

    // Constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Mapped to a table like this:

```
create table thingies (
    thingy_id serial primary key,
    thingy_name text,
    thingy_price smallint
);
```

Is there a way to make the provider aware of the attribute naming policy instead of needing to explicitly provide a @Column annotation on each getter? In other words, can we automatically map all underscored names to the corresponding camelcased names without using @Column?

(I know I can quote names, that is not an answer to my question above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following property to your persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
```

And all camelcasedproperty names will bemapped to underscored column names.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Column.

```
@Column(name="thingy_name")
private String thingyName;
```

Becouse 'thingy_name' is not equal 'thingyName'. JPA dont know what you want mapped. But in table thingyname and in entity thingyName is equal for JPA.

Use adnotation @Column, it does not take a lot of time. But you will get a  explicit documentation.